# Windows 7 can't connect

Tags: windows, networking

I've got following issue with may laptop toshiba (windows 7 , wifi card is atheros)

I cant connect with  my laptop (winodws 7) to my router and to the internet? I already installed  latest drivers and turned off firewall.

I cant even ping the router but I can see the mac in the routers table, as well Im not able ping my networks interfaces on the laptop from cmd.exe its saying general failure.

The other pc in the network has no problem with the router. (its dell with windows 7 )

Any idea what else should I check?

Comment: Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1 (localhost)?

Answer (score 1):

"Im not able ping my networks interfaces on the laptop from cmd.exe its saying general failure"

This can be a more serious issue, do a loopback test (determines whether the device is working right or not):

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

If this turns out to be unreachable/failed, you have issues with your network card as the TCP/IP stack is not working correctly.

If the test returns success, you should try and assign a fixed IP address.
The router at my work sometimes assigns weird IP addresses to my machine and I can't connect to anything, the DHCP has probably an issue.

Restart your router and try again, if that fails, assign a static IP address to your laptops's Wi-Fi.

If that still fails, try connecting through normal RJ-45 cable and see if the problem persists.